# Where is the command list for the default keys?

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to remapping some of the default keys, where I can find all the command name list used by vim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you find a complete list under `:help normal-index`

There is also a `insert-index`, `visual-index` and `ex-edit-index`